# Karate API - Getting 500 error while hitting SOAP service in batch

Tags: rest, web-services, soap, automated-tests, karate

I am automating 3 APIs (Rest_1, Rest_2 and Soap_3 services) using Karate API. Basically Rest_1 output will be input to Rest_2 and Rest_2 output will be input to Soap_3. Created 3 feature files for each API and one master feature file that calls these 3 features. Rest_1-->Rest_2 flow is working as expected, Rest_2-->Soap_3 request XML is generating as expected but the same request is not hitting the Soap_3 service and getting the response 500.

- When I execute Soap_3 feature file alone it is giving me the expected response. But in batch it is throwing 500 error.
- If I take Rest_2-->Soap_3 generated XML and run it in SoapUI manually it is working fine.

Request your help in this issue. Thanks in advance !

Below is my Soap_3 service feature file:

```
Feature: Get PolicyDetails

Background:

 * configure headers = {Content-Type: 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'}
 * configure logPrettyResponse = true
 * configure ssl = true
 * configure ssl = 'TLSv1.2'
 * header Authorization = call read('classpath:resources/common/basic_auth.js') {username:'test',password:'test'}
 * url 'https://soap_3apiurl'

Scenario: get the PolicyInfo

 * configure charset = null
 # getting submission id from preious feature file output
 * call read('classpath:resources/dynamic/previous.feature'){'submissionID':'#(submissionID)'}
 * xml req = read ('classpath:resources/common/RetrivePolicyDetails.xml')
 * karate.set ('req/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns2:retrieveSubmission/ns2:aRequest/SubmissionID',submissionID)

 Given request req
 When soap action 'https://soap3apiurl'
 Then status 200
 And print response

 **Console log:**

 16:43:30.562 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 58.18
 1 < 500
 1 < Accept-Encoding:
 1 < Authorization: Basic
 1 < Cneonction: close
 1 < Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8
 1 < Cookie: NSC
 1 < Date: 
 1 < Host: soap3APIurl.com
 1 < Set-Cookie: 
 1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 1 < X-Forwarded-For: 10.00.00.1, 10.00.00.20
 1 < X-Forwarded-Host: 
 1 < X-Forwarded-Server:
 1 < X-dynaTrace: FW1;10000008;-1100030439;601946;6;-11000009;60194;1
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
       <soapenv:Fault>
          <faultcode xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap11Env:Server</faultcode>
          <faultstring>Error while building message</faultstring>
       </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>

16:43:30.565 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - status code was: 500, expected: 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* configure headers = {Cookie : null}
```

Adding above line resolved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: For me, the test case is passed with 200 status when executing with one set of data in scenario outline. While running with multiple set of data with the same feature file give 502: Internal server error

Answer (score 0):

Do not leave a space after the `read` function reference:

```
* xml req = read('classpath:resources/common/RetrivePolicyDetails.xml')
```

This is explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#locator-lookup

If this is not the issue, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter Thomas. Tried after fixing the space and still it is giving the same error. Getting same error even if I give the Static XML. I will submit an issue.